# GPDR cookie popup in Playwright

Tags: javascript, popup, screenshot, headless, playwright

Hello I try to make a screenshot with Playwright but I have cookie EU law popup on my screenshots. How can I remove them ?

Here is my browser parameters.

```
const browser = await playwright.firefox.launch({
   headless: true,
   firefoxUserPrefs: {
    "network.cookie.cookieBehavior": 2
   }
});
```

But it don't work.
Thank for your help.

Comment: _“But it don't work”_ - why should it, what did you expect that to do? These popups are shown to inform the user, _that_ the site tries to use cookies. They do not magically disappear just because your browser _allows_ setting of cookies, they require user interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the playwright API to click the element. I'm using the text selector in the example below, but you can use [any selector](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fselectors.md&q=).

```js
const { webkit } = require('playwright');

(async() => {
    const browser = await webkit.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://npmjs.com');
    await page.click('text=Accept');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```